# Вывести список папок на php.

Tags: php

Предположим, существует папка *index*. В ней папки *Andrej, Anton, Viktor, Volodja, Aleksandr, Dima, Serjozha и т.д.* Как вывести на страницу список папок, которые находятся внутри папки *index*?

Comment: такой вопрос должно быть стыдно задавать, потому что простейший гуглинг сразу даст результат

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$dir = opendir('index');
while($file = readdir($dir)) {
   if (is_dir('index/'.$file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..') {
       echo $file."\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Лучше `scandir`, там можно сортировку задать.